# Como dar um POST na página com a propriedade UPLOAD sem entrar em looping?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Procurando na internet vi alguns sites dizendo que quando tem um propriedade **Upload** na página não pode dar **POST** na mesma porque entra em *looping*.

Tenho uma aplicação que cria/excluí pastas e exibi um mensagem de alerta(server) onde da um **POST** na página fazendo assim entrar no *looping*, e assim retornando erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha pergunta seria, como dar um **POST** na página afim de atualizar as informações do formulário sem entrar nesse *looping*?

Exemplo do evento de Carregar o Arquivo do FileUpload:

```
protected void BtnCarregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string caminho = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PastaRaiz"];
            var source = Directory.GetDirectories(caminho).Select(c => new DirectoryInfo(c).Name).ToList();
            if (ddlFolders.SelectedValue != null)
            {
                if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                {
                    string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
                    if (!Directory.Exists(caminho + ddlFolders.SelectedValue + "/" + fileName))
                    {
                        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(caminho + ddlFolders.SelectedValue + "/" + fileName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mensagens.ExibirMensagem("Mensagem", "Arquivo já existente no diretório.", false, this.Page, this.GetType());
                    }
                }
            }
            mensagens.ExibirMensagem("Mensagem", "Arquivo  carregado com sucesso.", false, this.Page, this.GetType());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Tem algum exemplo de código para colocar na sua pergunta?

Comment: @Don'tPanic adicionado

Comment: Qual é o erro apresentado?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Não é exatamente um erro, mas seu eu dou POST nessa página ela fica em um looping nesse evento. Porém se eu não dou o POST não consigo atualizar o formulário, pq tudo é feito via side Server

Comment: Me parece que você está confundindo loot com demora na resposta. Se o usuário está fazendo o upload de um arquivo,  o request ficará "suspenso" até o final dessa carga

Comment: @LeandroAngelo não é isso. Eu não salvo no banco de dados, assim não preciso fazer conversão de dados. É direto para um diretório físico.
Eu adicionei a pergunta a imagem que me retorna quando tento atualizar a página.

Comment: Essa imagem é de quando você tenta atualizar a página de um form que já foi postada e não houve redirect para um destino diferente. No seu caso, pelo evento de click, suponho que se trata de webform e um postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dito nos comentários, isso acontece porque ao clicar no botão de `bntCarregar` você está invocando um evento no backend, que por sua vez é disparado por um post no lado do client, o famoso PostBack do WebForms. No browser é um submit comum, mas no asp.net isso pode disparar outros eventos que alteram componentes e que por sua vez podem estar configurados para realizar um novo postback quando têm seu estado alterado.

Você deve acrecentar o tratamento adequado no método `Page_Load()` da sua página. E ou mapear o que está encadeando esse loop.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //... Tratamentos necessários para o carregamento correto da sua página
    }
}
```

Obs.: Minha suspeita é de que o "loop" esteja relacionado ao método `ExibirMensagem()`, uma vez que ele recebe o `this.Page` como parâmetro